# Invoke method for dynamic object

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic-programming

I have a class like bellow:

```
@interface Validator : NSObject
- (BOOL)validateParameters:(NSDictionary *)data;
@end
```

and I am creating an object of Validator class dynamically like:

```
Class validatorClass = NSClassFromString(@"Validator");
id _validObject = [[validatorClass alloc] init];
```

Now I want to access that validateParameters: method and use the return value in the caller method with that dynamic object.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you tried `[_validObject validateParameters:<object>];` ?

Comment: how to get return value then, got the solution. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use method

> **performSelector:withObject:**

if you have only one parameter. This is example:

```
  Class validatorClass = NSClassFromString(@"Validator");
  id _validObject = [[validatorClass alloc] init];
  BOOL result = [_validObject performSelector:@selector(validateParameters:) withObject:[NSData data]];
```

Also you can use **NSInvocation** class.

```
  Class validatorClass = NSClassFromString(@"Validator");
  id _validObject = [[validatorClass alloc] init];
  NSInvocation* invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[_validObject methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(validateParameters:)]];
  invocation.target = _validObject;
  invocation.selector =@selector(validateParameters:);
  [invocation setArgument:(__bridge void * _Nonnull)([NSData data]) atIndex:2];
  [invocation invoke];
  BOOL result;
  [invocation getReturnValue:&result];
```

NOTE: You need add argument started with 2 index, because 0 and 1 index is a target and selector

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for Dynamic Object Allocation And Method calling in `Objective-C`

> _validObject -> is your dynamic object

```
Class validatorClass = NSClassFromString(@"Validator");
id _validObject = [[validatorClass alloc] init];

//Call with That dynamic Object
[_validObject validateParameters:[NSDictionary dictionary]];
```

Hope this will helps.

Comment: actually need to get the return value, answer from Sergey worked. thank you for your reply